# Microsoft Teams Development : Unable to get messageReaction event in Microsoft teams - Messaging Extension

Tags: azure, bots

I am developing Microsoft bot for messaging extension where I am using botbuilder-teams node module.

```
var teams =  require('botbuilder-teams');
var connector = new teams.TeamsChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
    openIdMetadata: process.env.BotOpenIdMetadata
});
```

Using TeamsChatConnector object I am able to get bot and its session and onQuery event which handles all interactions in the messaging extension window.:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
var session = bot.session;
connector.onQuery('searchCmd',composeExtensionHandler);
var composeExtensionHandler = function(event,query,callback){
  // here we can write code to handle query request.

}
```

searchCmd is a commandId mentioned in manifest file.

I want 'messageReaction' event which gives me card actions as 'when A user adds/removes his or her reaction to a bot message'
such as a like reaction as shown in below image:[image]

In TeamsChatConnector class I found some methods Ex: onDispatchEvents, dispatchEventOrQuery, onFileConsentCardResponse. can we use any one of these method or any other method to get 'messageReaction' event and if yes how to use that method.